# Stopping a large number of zeros being printed (not scientific notation)

Tags: r, printing, numbers, digits, scientific-notation

What I'm trying to achieve is to have all printed numbers display at maximum `7` digits. Here are examples of what I want printed:

> 0.000000   (versus the actual number which is 0.000000000029481.....)
>
> 0.299180    (versus the actual number which is 0.299180291884922.....)

I've had success with the latter types of numbers by using `options(scipen=99999)` and `options(digits=6)`. However, the former example will always print a huge number of zeros followed by five non-zero digits. **How do I stop this from occurring and achieve my desired result**? *I also do not want scientific notation*.

*I want this to apply to ALL printed numbers in EVERY context. For example if I have some matrix, call it `A`, and I print this matrix, I want every element to just be 6-7 digits. I want this to be automatic for every print in every context; just like using `options(digits=6)` and `options(scipen=99999)` makes it automatic for every context.*

Comment: What if you have a large number, for example 123456789.87654321. How can you print it using at most 7 digits if you are not going to use scientific notation?!

Comment: @flodel Good point. Maybe I would like these very large numbers to use scientific notation (or extend beyond 6 digits). But if there only exists a solution that truncates EVERY dumber do 6-7 digits; that's fine, since I never work with large numbers that I need to print in the R console.

Answer (score 12):

You can define a new print method for the type you wish to print. For example, if all your numbers are doubles, you can create

```
print.double=function(x){sprintf("%.6f", x)}
```

Now, when you print a double (or a vector of doubles), the function `print.double()` will be called instead of `print.default()`.

You may have to create similar functions `print.integer()`, `print.complex()`, etc., depending on the types you need to print.

To return to the default print method, simply delete the function `print.double()`.

Answer (score 3):

Are all your numbers < 1? You could try a simple `sprintf( "%.6f", x )`. Otherwise you could try wrapping things to `sprintf` based on the number of digits; check `?sprintf` for other details.

Comment: I want this to automatically apply to every single number print; a solution that's similar to `options(digits=6)` in that it just applies to every object in every context and I only need to set it *once*. Not everything is < 1, but everything *that I need to print interactively* is < 100.